# How to integrate WSO2 (BPEL Engine) with Dot Net web application

Tags: wso2

Please help me out in integrating WSO2 (BPEL Engine) with Dot Net web application.

I have a web application developed in Dot Net 4.5 framework. I am able to generate BPEL compliant XML and WSDL file with my application. My question is how will I drive my BPEL XML and WSDL file with WSO2 (BPEL Engine). What are the steps to integrate it.

Does WSO2 provide some API so that we may pass BPEL XML file and WSDL file and BPEL engine may execute it and return the response.